# the program have to put the odd-index elements in a new vector C and the even-index elements in another vector T

Tags: c++

I have to make a program that after entering the elements of a vector `v[n]`, the program have to put the odd-index elements in a new vector `C` and the even-index elements in another vector `T`. The code seems to work but the result is not complete. It shows just one element at both vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int el,c[100],t[100],count=0, count1=0,v[100];
    cout<<"How many elements : \n"<<endl;
    cin>>el;
    for(int i=0;i<el;i++){
        cout<<"Enter element "<<i+1<<" "<<endl;
        cin>>v[i];
    }
    for(int i=0,j=0,z=0;i<el;i++){
        if(v[i]%2==0){
            count++;
            c[j]=v[i];
            j++;
        }
        else{
            t[z]=v[i];
            count1++;
            z++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Odd vector "<<endl;
    for(int j=0;j<count;j++){
        cout<<"Elements"<<"     "<<c[j]<<endl;
    cout<<"Even vector "<<endl;
    for(int z=0;z<count1;z++){
        cout<<"Elements "<<"     "<<t[z]<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    }
}
```

Expected result:
Example: I give the `v[]={3,5,7,8,9,6}`

The program should give this result:

```
Odd elements
3  7  9
Even elements
5  8  6
```

Actual result is:

```
Odd elements 
8
Even elements 
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your braces are incorrect when you print out the results

```
cout<<"Odd vector "<<endl;
for(int j=0;j<count;j++){
    cout<<"Elements"<<"     "<<c[j]<<endl;
cout<<"Even vector "<<endl;
for(int z=0;z<count1;z++){
    cout<<"Elements "<<"     "<<t[z]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
}
```

should be

```
cout<<"Odd vector "<<endl;
for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
    cout<<"Elements"<<"     "<<c[j]<<endl;
cout<<"Even vector "<<endl;
for(int z=0;z<count1;z++)
    cout<<"Elements "<<"     "<<t[z]<<endl;
return 0;
```

The way you have it `return 0;` is inside the second for loop, which is inside the first for loop, so both loops only print out one number before your program exits.

Comment: Also `v[i]%2==0` returns true if `v[i]` is not divisible by 2 (i.e is odd). Should be the other way around.

Comment: @betrunken I left that issue because the problem descrption talks about even and odd *indexes* so maybe it should be `if (i%2 != 0)`

Comment: true. But their example is separated by values.

Comment: thanks a lot guys now it works just fine .Been looking for a while where the problem was thank you again for the help